# HackerRank Compare the Triplet. JavaScript solution vs. Python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

So, I am trying to solve Compare the Triplets problem from HackerRank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem).

My JavaScript solution passes all test cases, but Python3 fails some of them (HackerRank doesn't allow to see which ones). As you can see I followed same logic but in Python it doesn't work. What is the difference between my Python and JS code?

JS:

```
function solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2){
var alice = ( a0 > b0 ? 1 : 0 ) + ( a1 > b1 ? 1 : 0 ) + ( a2 > b2 ? 1 : 0 );
var bob = ( a0 < b0 ? 1 : 0 ) + ( a1 < b1 ? 1 : 0 ) + ( a2 < b2 ? 1 : 0 );

return [alice, bob];
```

}

Python3:

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2):
alice = 1 if a0 > b0 else 0 + 1 if a1 >v b1 else 0 + 1 if a2 > b2 else 0
bob = 1 if a0 < b0 else 0 + 1 if a1 < b1 else 0 + 1 if a2 < b2 else 0
return (alice, bob)
```

Comment: You decided not to use parentheses in the Python version for some reason…? The conditional operator still has lower precedence than `+`. (`bool` is also an `int` subclass, so you can just `(a0 > b0) + (a1 > b1) + (a2 > b2)`, and the same in JS.)

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses after every if/else

```
        alice = (1 if (a0>b0) else 0) + (1 if (a1>b1) else 0) + (1 if (a2>b2) else 0)
        bob = (1 if (a0<b0) else 0) + (1 if (a1<b1) else 0) + (1 if (a2<b2) else 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    total_a = 0
    total_b = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] > b[i]:
            total_a = total_a + 1
        elif a[i] < b[i]:
            total_b = total_b + 1
    return (total_a, total_b)
```

Fortunately, I got the logic which is same as of Geraldo Braho, but struggled to get the logic in "For Loop Expression", I got the answer that I need to use range before "len(a)/len(b)" as both have the same lengths in this case. Big thanks to Mr. Geraldo Braho for teaching me that we need to use "range(len(a))" in  the "For Loop Expression".

https://geraldo1993.github.io/articles/Compare-the-Triplets/

Answer (score 0):

You should use parenthesis after every if/else statement. because python `bool` need parenthesis for 100% accuracy. Comparison has a higher precedence than Boolean operators. here's you'r modified code below:

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2):
  a = (1 if a0 > b0 else 0) + (1 if a1 > b1 else 0) + (1 if a2 > b2 else 0)
  b = (1 if a0 < b0 else 0) + (1 if a1 < b1 else 0) + (1 if a2 < b2 else 0)
  return (a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what others answered above, you need to parenthesize your bool operations. But regarding your python code, this is a better way to write it.

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    alice = sum(1 for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] > b[i] and not a[i] == b[i])
    bob = sum(1 for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] and not a[i] == b[i] and not a[i] > b[i])
    return [alice, bob]
```

Each line in the alice and bob variable loops over a range (in this case we put the length of array a, since both a and b arrays have the same length) and will yield a value of `1` for each time the conditions,

`if a[i] > b[i] and not a[i] == b[i]` for alice, and

`if a[i] and not a[i] == b[i] and not a[i] > b[i]` for bob is satisfied,

which will then be summated as the integer value of each variable of alice and bob. The question in hacker rank asks you to display it in an array so you need to return it as array.

Comment: The question was about what the difference between the two sections of code was. When adding an answer to an older question be sure to note what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding an explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    const alice = a
    const bob = b
    let aliceTotal = 0
    let bobTotal = 0
    
    for (let i = 0; i < alice.length; i++) {
        if (alice[i] > bob[i]) {
            aliceTotal = aliceTotal + 1
        } else if (bob[i] > alice[i]) {
            bobTotal = bobTotal + 1
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
    return [aliceTotal, bobTotal]
}
```

as you can see this function is looping the array input and comparing the value of the same index of array and if the one get higher value the total is adding 1 point.

this is my answer i hope this can help.

Answer (score -1):

i Hope, This Also helps

```
a = list(map(int, input("Enter The First input").split()))
b = list(map(int, input("Enter The Second input").split()))

a_score = b_score = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        a_score += 1
    elif a[i] < b[i]:
        b_score +=1
    else:
        pass

print(a_score, b_score)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
d, g = (0, 0)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        d += 1
    elif b[i] > a[i]:
        g += 1
return d, g


a = [int(i) for i in input('value of a').split(",")]
b = [int(i) for i in input('value of a').split(",")]
print(compareTriplets(a, b))
```

Comment: Compare the triplets using python